# Is it possible to get how many positional arguments does a function need in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection

I am looking for a way to get how many positional arguments does a function need in Python 3.
Like this:

```py
def a():pass # 0 positional arguments
def b(x):pass # 1 positional argument
def c(x=0):pass # 0 positional arguments
def d(x,y=0):pass # 1 positional argument
def e(x,y):pass # 2 positional arguments
def f(x=0,y=0):pass # 0 positional arguments
```

Comment: Technically, both functions `d` and `f` have two positional arguments, because they can be called as `d(1, 2)` and `f(3, 4)`.

Comment: I mean, you are able to answer the question by looking at the code, apparently. Are you trying to do some kind of metaprogramming? If so, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module for this:

```
import inspect

def count_positional_args_required(func):
    signature = inspect.signature(func)
    empty = inspect.Parameter.empty
    total = 0
    for param in signature.parameters.values():
        if param.default is empty:
            total += 1
    return total

def a():pass # 0 positional arguments
def b(x):pass # 1 positional argument
def c(x=0):pass # 0 positional arguments
def d(x,y=0):pass # 1 positional argument
def e(x,y):pass # 2 positional arguments
def f(x=0,y=0):pass # 0 positional arguments

for func in [a,b,c,d,e,f]:
    print(count_positional_args_required(func))
```

EDIT:
The above only works for non-built-in  functions.

Comment: What was wrong with the duplicate closure?

Comment: @Chen-Y0y0 at least 3.3 and above

Comment: @KarlKnechtel there were too many, and I didn't see that the last one actually answered the question, my bad

Comment: This doesn't work when `func` is `print`.

Comment: @Chen-Y0y0 yes, it won't work with built-in functions (i.e. functions written in C)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Is this always work on user-defined functions?

Comment: @Chen-Y0y0 yes, it should. And on second thought, you don't need `POSITIONAL_KINDS`, I don't think.